# Triplet state with symmetric wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, parity

In the $1s,2s$ electronic configuration, I've found that the possible states are <sup>1</sup>S<sub>0</sub> and <sup>3</sup>S<sub>1</sub>.

$L=0$ for both of these terms, so would the parity of the spatial wave function not be $(-1)^L=1$, and therefore symmetric, for both of these terms?

The first singlet state was straightforward but for the triplet states where the spin terms are also symmetric, how should the wave function be written- with a symmetric or an antisymmetric spatial term?

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

Combining two spin half systems generates either a total spin $S=1$ or a total spin $S=0$. In fact $$|s_1-s_2|\leq S \leq s_1+s_2\implies 0\leq S \leq 1$$ which means that you'll have a state for which the total spin is zero, which is the singlet state and three state for which the total spin is $S=1$. They are three beause you'll have three possible z-projections of the spin $S_z = \pm1, 0$. The spatial part of the total wavefunction will depend on wheter the spin part is symmetric or antisymmetric.

### Long Answer

Whether the spatial part of the wavefunction is going to be symmetric or antisymmetric depends on the spin part of the total wavefunction, as said. Since the total wavefunction has to be antisymmetric to satisfy Pauli exclusion principle if you have a spin wavefunction which is symmetric then the spatial part has to be antisymmetric and viceversa.

Practically speaking you'll have two possible spatial wavefunction in the $1s2s$ electron configuration given as a combination of $\psi_i(x)$ where $i=1s,2s$ are single electron wavefunctions on a given orbital $$\Psi_S =\frac{\psi_{1s}(x)\psi_{2s}(y)+\psi_{2s}(x)\psi_{1s}(y)}{\sqrt{2}}\qquad\Psi_A = \frac{\psi_{1s}(x)\psi_{2s}(y)-\psi_{2s}(x)\psi_{1s}(y)}{\sqrt{2}}$$ Evidently the first is symmetric and the second antisymmetric.

Now we come to the spin part of the wavefunction. It's easy to see that if you have $2$ electrons to put on two different electronic levels you have four ways of putting their spin. One way is of putting both spins up, or both spin down. The other two ways is to put the one in $1s$ spin up while the one in $2s$ spin down and viceversa. The way to combine is to use addition of angular momenta which in this case is easily done by using Clebsh-Gordan coefficients which are tabulated $$\begin{align}
&\chi_{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}= \left|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle\left|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle = |1,1\rangle \\
&\chi_{\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}}= \left|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle\left|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|1,0\rangle+|0,0\rangle\right)\\
&\chi_{-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}= \left|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle\left|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|1,0\rangle-|0,0\rangle\right)\\
&\chi_{-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}}= \left|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle\left|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle = |1,-1\rangle\end{align}$$

Now you can see that three spin wavefunctions are symmetric, namely the first, second and fourth while the other is antisymmetric.

Using the fact that the total wavefunction *has to be antisymmetric* there are only some ways in which we can combine the spatial wavefunction with the spin one, and are as follows $$\Psi_S\chi_{-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}\qquad\Psi_A\chi_{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}\qquad\Psi_A\chi_{\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}}\qquad\Psi_A\chi_{-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}}$$ which give you exactly the singlet state and the triplet state.